# Preview Package in LaTeX trim the \widetilde

Tags: macros, pdftex, preview

Forgive my dummy question, i am not professional in LaTeX.

I use `Preview` package to crop the inline formulas' borders exactly to the mathematical notation but i noticed the following:

after using `Preview` Package with `$\widetilde{\mathbf{l}}$`, i got the following result:

[image: Current Result with <code>preview</code> Package]

but what i expect to have is something like:

[image]

You can easily notice that there are some trimmed parts at the start and the end of `\widetilde{}` caused by `Preview` package

Minimal Example of LaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage,displaymath,textmath]{preview}
\begin{document}


\noindent 
            $\widetilde{\mathbf{l}}$

\end{document}
```

can any one explain that behavior to me ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

Glyphs can be larger than their bounding box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\fboxsep0pt
\fbox{$\widetilde{\mathbf{l}}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can enlarge the border of preview by changing the length `\PreviewBorder`

Comment: Thank you for your help, i actually tried to use \PreviewBorder length and set it to "0.05" but i got the same result and then i tried to increase the value to "1.5" and got a good result but i use that globally with all inline formulas and finally i got one case solved but other cases have extra spaces more than what the character deserves.

Comment: Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: @MohamedSayed: There is no way to solve this automatically. Preview doesn't see the ink, only the bounding box. You will have to adjust the problematic equations. Or don't use widetilde over an i, it looks a bit odd anyway.